# Xcode doesn't load unit tests

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Since couple of weeks ago (probably after I've updated my macbook to Sonoma 14.3.1) my Xcode cannot load unit test.

When opening Test Navigator all I see is: Loading Tests... and it stays forever in that state.

[image: loading tests]

This is a completely new project and it's crazy. The only way I can start testing is if I use CMD+U to run all the tests. And since this is my company's project, it takes a lot of time.
Also there's no option to click on test-diamond-shaped button to run individual tests.

I also tried checking "Test Plans", but I get an infinite progress view:

[image: infinite loading]

Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

I tried to remove the Derived Data, reinstall Xcode (and different versions), did `git clean -fxd`, nothing helped.
Also some function like: "Rename", "Edit all in scope" stopped working as well.

Comment: Do you have a example project?

Comment: This happens on all projects, these screenshots are from brand new project.